# Adding multiple tiny mce editors in plugin page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, tinymce

i'm using this code to add tiny mce in my plugin page in wordpress 3.2.1

```
// attach the tiny mce editor to this textarea
if (function_exists('wp_tiny_mce')) {

  add_filter('teeny_mce_before_init', create_function('$a', '
    $a["theme"] = "advanced";
    $a["skin"] = "wp_theme";
    $a["height"] = "200";
    $a["width"] = "800";
    $a["onpageload"] = "";
    $a["mode"] = "exact";
    $a["elements"] = "mytextarea";
    $a["editor_selector"] = "mceEditor";
    $a["plugins"] = "safari,inlinepopups,spellchecker";

    $a["forced_root_block"] = false;
    $a["force_br_newlines"] = true;
    $a["force_p_newlines"] = false;
    $a["convert_newlines_to_brs"] = true;

    return $a;'));

 wp_tiny_mce(true);
}
```

How is it possibile to change another textarea id=mytextarea2 into a tiny mce editor in the same plugin admin page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've found a proper solution: addinge the second id to the elements parameter:

```
// attach the tiny mce editor to this textarea
if (function_exists('wp_tiny_mce')) {

  add_filter('teeny_mce_before_init', create_function('$a', '
    $a["theme"] = "advanced";
    $a["skin"] = "wp_theme";
    $a["height"] = "200";
    $a["width"] = "800";
    $a["onpageload"] = "";
    $a["mode"] = "exact";
    $a["elements"] = "mytextarea,mytextarea2";
    $a["editor_selector"] = "mceEditor";
    $a["plugins"] = "safari,inlinepopups,spellchecker";

    $a["forced_root_block"] = false;
    $a["force_br_newlines"] = true;
    $a["force_p_newlines"] = false;
    $a["convert_newlines_to_brs"] = true;

    return $a;'));

 wp_tiny_mce(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `the_editor($content, $id);` where $content is your HTML and $id is your form name and id attribute.  You may have to call `wp_tiny_mce()` after that if there or no other instances on the edit page (like the default content editor.)

---Edit for clarity...

`the_editor()` outputs the entire TinyMCE/HTML tabbed editor section.  You can call this as many times as you need.

`wp_tiny_mce()` outputs the TinyMCE initialization script tag, so should only be called once per page.

Answer (score 1):

From [this article](http://maxfoundry.com/blog/2011/11/04/how-to-add-multiple-tinymce-editors-to-your-wordpress-theme-or-plugin/).

The "editor_selector" is based on the class attribute.

So, just use the same class to all textareas you want to use TinyMCE.